# How to mock "remove" extension of shared preferences using mockk?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, sharedpreferences, mockk

### Problem Description

I have a method of a data source class that makes the following call to a Shared Preferences extension:

```kotlin
override suspend fun removePendingBatch() {
    preferences.remove(pendingBatchKey)
}
```

**preferences** is an instance of [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

I need to do an unit test using *mockk* that checks if when calling this method of my data source class the call to this shared preferences extension is made.

In my test scenario I instantiate my preferences object like this:

```kotlin
private val preferences: SharedPreferences = mockk()
```

This is my unit test:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `when removePendingBatch() is called then remove from preferences`() = runBlockingTest {
    every { preferences.remove(PENDING_BATCH_KEY) } just runs
    batchDataSource.removePendingBatch()
    verify(exactly = 1) { preferences.remove(PENDING_BATCH_KEY) }
}
```

The problem happens when I try to run this unit test, a mockk error saying there is no mock response is thrown:

```
no answer found for: Editor(child of #1#3).commit()
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: Editor(child of #1#3).commit()
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:90)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:263)
...
```

### My attempt fails

I imagine that I should mock the editor method call inside the shared preferences, however it seems to me that the *mockk* can't do that very well with the `just runs` statement, because when trying to do it the following syntax error appears:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by mocking the `commit` method coming from the `SharedPreferences.Editor` object by this way:

```
every { preferences.edit().commit() } returns RandomUtils.nextBoolean()
```

In this case, just return any boolean, so we can mock the "remove" method, my complete test looks like this:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `when removePendingBatch() is called then remove from preferences`() = runBlockingTest {
    every { preferences.edit().commit() } returns RandomUtils.nextBoolean()
    every { preferences.remove(PENDING_BATCH_KEY) } just runs
    batchDataSource.removePendingBatch()
    verify(exactly = 1) { preferences.remove(PENDING_BATCH_KEY) }
}
```